# Call a Overloaded Function of Inherited Class from Base Class

Tags: c++

```c
#include<iostream>

class A {
    public:
        void init(){
                std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        }
};
class B: public A {
    public:
    void init(){
            std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
        A *o = new B();

/*

Some codes here

*/
        o->init();
        return 0;
}
```

Result:
A

In the above program, the init called is of class A. How do I call the init function of class B?

edit: I need to call both the `init`s. I can't change the A and B class. And I have to make the object declaration like that in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options here:

```
B *o = new B(); // in Main
```

or

```
(B *)o->init(); // in Main
```

or

```
virtual void init(){
                       std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
                   } // in Class A
```

Comment: it's `((B *)o)->init()`. I was making a stupid mistake. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Make the `init()` function virtual in `Class A`.

```
class A {
    public:
        virtual void init(){
                std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

The object `o` has two parts. The `base part` and the `derived part`. If you want `B::init()` to be called from `o`, then you will have to tell the compiler that it is a virtual function and it should look for the function overload in the derived class.

I suggest you go through the tutorial on this website to learn more about inheritance:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/113-order-of-construction-of-derived-classes/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can't change the classes. Prewritten API :/

Answer (score 0):

```
b = dynamic_cast<B*>(o);
if(b!=NULL)
   b->init();
```

this will call the function for object of type B.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think for that I need to declare the functions as virtual. I can't change the classes. Prewritten API :/

Comment: @subhabrata no, you dont need to. this will work as long as B is derived class of A

Answer (score 0):

make init function virtual 
create a pointer of class A
create an object of class B
assign address of B object to pointer A
now access init function of B

Answer (score 0):

since class B hides the definition of init() in its base-class, it will make the function sensitive to the type of any pointer or reference from which the function might be called.
And as you mentioned A and B are prewritten class, you can instantiate a pointer to class B, or cast to a pointer to class B.